# Is there a way to make a multi select dropdown look like a normal dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make my dropdown to support multi-select feature. But from display purpose, I want to modify it. It should be visible to end user as a normal dropwn.

```html
<select type="text" className="form-control" name="filterOptions" id="filterOptions" 
  onChange={(e)=> {self.optionsChange(e, item)}} style={{marginTop:"0px"}} multiple>
  <option key="select" value="allValues">All Values</option>
  {self.renderFilterOptions(item)}
</select>
```

This is my code for dropdown. Is it possible with some css or little bit modification, that the static value "All Values", will appear at the top of the dropdown, clicking on which will show other options, with the ability of multi select.

Or if not possible, then is there a way to add checkbox to a normal dropdown. Checkbox should be added to all the options. This will also help me..

Please guide me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would be way easier to use a plugin. Multiselect dropdown in normal html is not very user friendly. I recommend using Select2 or using Material Theme.

Comment: I have tried to use react-select and multiselect-react-dropdown plugin, but those are not meeting my objective. If there is some way that my above code can be converted to something better, then it'll be good.